# How to Check with PHP if someone is uploading something on my FTP server

Tags: php, ftp

I hâve users sending files on my FTP server. I am processing those files at midnight batch wise. Before launching my php script i want to make sure that there is nobody uploading at that Time. Is it possible to Check this using PHP?

Comment: This sounds either unnecessary, or like just a bad idea. Why wouldn't uploads completed after 00:00 simply be processed on the next day?

Comment: Hello Jonathon :) Because the user might send the data at that time of processing...

Comment: There's no particular way of doing this in PHP. You could run a CRON to knock off FTP service before midnight, run your PHP, then reenable it five minutes after... If youre that bothered... But I cant see it being worth the workload. If someone uploads at midnight, it just wont be run that day. If someone cant upload just before midnight, its just tough luck, they will have to wait for the next one :)

Comment: Hello Scarraban :) do you know if a file with an upload in progress Will be listed on the server during upload?

Comment: @Marc So what? At the start of your "batch operation", you get the list of (completed upload) files in the uploads directory. You then operate on those files, and delete them if necessary. Since you're only working on the "snapshot" taken at 00:00, any files uploaded after that point will remain until the next batch operation. Simple.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a cron job to create a file for upload of each date at 12:00:00, and then batch process the contents of that file a few minutes later (to give any currently uploading files time to process).

Then all the files for the next day will go into their own folder.